# Is there any way to attach a directive to a component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a simple panel component:

```
<app-box></app-box>
```

And it has a template:

```
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header">
      <h3>Box Header</h3>
      <small>Subtitle of this box</small>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there anyway I can use a directive attached to it so I can manipulate the DOM like this:

```
<app-box subtitle="false"></app-box>
```

When `subtitle` is `false` I want to remove the `small` element.

Also, is this a wrong technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use inputs:

```
@Input() subtitle: boolean;
```

and in your html:

```
<small *ngIf="subtitle">...</small>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! But if I have multiple <app-box> it will get the last value of subtitle.

Comment: Do you instantiate multiple app boxes using `ngFor`?

Comment: No. Just different boxes (multiple <app-box>) with different classes / colors etc.

Comment: Not sure I got it. If you instantiate a few, each should get its own value so there is no 'clash'. Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: `<app-box subtitle="false"></app-box>
        <app-box subtitle="true"></app-box>
        <app-box subtitle="true" [ngClass]="['darker']"></app-box>`

Comment: So in this case all subtitles are true (even the first one)?

Comment: Exactly, and it's just a simple  `<small *ngIf="subtitle">Subtitle of this box</small>` +   `@Input() subtitle: boolean;` . Or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you set it up on plunkr? It will be easier to see